# Outlook Add-in Message Compose Form

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to add a custom information field to the mail detail form based on some selection made in the task pane?

Following image shows a mock up of my requirement.

[image: Requirement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** possible to add the custom form field by using Office.js API. If you have business requirements you may use [officespdev.uservoice.com](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=131778) website to make the request for new feature or upvote existing one.

As the work around you probably may use [Office.NotificationMessages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_5/office.NotificationMessages?product=outlook&version=v1.5&view=office-js#addAsync) object to display your custom information. It will appear above the message fields and has certain limitation (for example length of supplied message). This may looks like ...

[image]

Comment: I will probably go with this solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link :
[adding-custom-data-to-outlook-e-mails](http://www.taskconnect.com/blog/adding-custom-data-to-outlook-e-mails)

Codes:

```
public static void SetUserProperty(this MailItem mail, string value)
{
  mail.UserProperties.Add("myKey", OlUserPropertyType.olText, 
    true, OlFormatText.olFormatTextText);
  mail.UserProperties["myKey"].Value = value;
}
```

[Outlook Addin to add custom field to mail form or accessing existing field with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955853/outlook-addin-to-add-custom-field-to-mail-form-or-accessing-existing-field-with)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the UI of the IPM.Note form (including the header area) using the Outlook Forms Designer (via the Developer Ribbon tab -> Design This Form). You can also create custom fields/properties in the designer using the Field Chooser tool window. Those properties will be available in the MailItem.UserProperties collection for read/write access

However custom forms are a legacy technology and discouraged from use due to the limitations and historical problems with managing and deploying custom form definitions.  You can instead use a Form Region (with or without a companion add-in), but the UI is limited to adjoining (or replace all) areas and wouldn't quite be in the header (but close).

Comment: Hi Eric, long time no see ;) The question tagged with OfficeJS API.